# is it possible to import sql file to mysql database from a url

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to import an SQL file to my database. The problem is that I can't get this file to my computer because it is too big file.

I want to import it from the server through it's URL using MySQL or phpMyAdmin

Is it possible? How can I do that?

Comment: `GET http://example.com/mysqldump.sql | mysql -D mydb -u myuser -pmypasswd`

Comment: why can you not download file to your machine and then execute `mysql -u USER -p PASSWORD DATABASENAME < importedFile.sql` ?

Comment: i don't have access to the shell so i can't use shell commands

Comment: @Nishant the file size in 600MB

Comment: No matter what process you use, the 600MB data has to be transferred to the client machine from the server. Download it or not, the data-transfer and most likely the time consumed in the process will stay the same. 600MB is not big file though. You may tar|zip|rar it at the server, download, (un)tar|zip|rar and import to MySQL, is the best.

Comment: is there any way that i can import it from the url using phpmyadmin or sql command

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible if the file is accessible through a url

```
curl 'http://whatever' | mysql -u username -p db_name
```

Comment: You really should attribute the user and answer you copy things from. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12294258/64976

Comment: And while posting this (copy) as an answer, you haven't even upvoted or accepted the answer you copied from, in your copied question.

Comment: I had to remove the space between -u and username and included -pPASSWORD.