# Script for Import mysql database from particular file location

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is it possible to import sql file to mysql database from a url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745920/is-it-possible-to-import-sql-file-to-mysql-database-from-a-url)

I want to import an SQL file to my database.
The problem is that I can't get this file to my computer because it is too big file.

I want to import it from the server through it's **URL using** MySQL.

Comment: Why is this tagged PHP instead of MYSQL?

Comment: Actually i want a php script to execute this commond by using exec() function..Thank for query...

Comment: It can execute the command in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If the file is accessible through a URL, you can do:

```
curl 'http://whatever' | mysql -u username -p db_name
```

Comment: Can you explain the intuition behind this? I have an AWS S3 link of a large SQL file. I'm trying to get the file on the S3 server to load on another separate AWS RDB server.

Comment: @jhub1 `curl` prints the contents of the URL to standard output. If the URL contains SQL queries, you can pipe it to `mysql` and it will execute them.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered just using mysql command line, like:

```
mysql -h hostname -u username -p db_name < /path/to/dump_script.sql
```

Look here for more information

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html

Comment: this solution is not working when we are dealing with a url.